# How to change the font in windows phone 8?

Tags: fonts, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I use the "**Lucida Handwriting**" for one textblock control at design time.

But i run it on emulator it is take someone font like

**At Design Time**

[image]

**At Run on Emulator**

[image]

How is Possible. How can i solve this difference. Please Help Me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you including the font file in your app package?

1) Add the font file that you wish to use to your project, and set the Build Action to Embedded Resource.  Also ensure you are copying the file to the assembly in the "Copy to output directory" property.
2) Select your textblock, and pull down the font selection dropdown in properties.

You should see your font there, and it will be compiled into the assembly and available for use in the app.

Comment: I don't add any font file in my app. But in design time the font is there in windows phone 8 sdk. But it's not work in runtime. Then How and why we import the fonts in resource file.

Comment: The font may not be available on the device / emulator so you will need to explicitly include it as per my edited answer above.