# How can I get a UWP Phone app to respect FontFamily?

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-phone-emulator

I have a trivial UWP app with the following included in main.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Border Background="Black">
        <TextBlock
            x:Name="bob"
            FontFamily="Segoe UI Mono"
            FontSize="12"
            Foreground="White"
            Text=“Whatever”
            />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

As a desktop app, the text appears in the chosen font family. But in a phone emulator, the FontFamily is ignored completely.

Is there a way for Windows Phone to respect the FontFamily selection? Do I need to explicitly  include my font in the app itself?

Comment: Looks like [you have to embed it to the app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16215589/815938).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your phone may lose this font.

Try to add the font to your solution.

Add a folder called `Font`

And you should add the font file to Font folder like this picture.

[image]

You should change your code.

```
    <TextBlock Margin="10,100,10,10"
               FontFamily="Font/And Love St.ttf#And Love st"
               Text="Lov ms" ></TextBlock>
```

If you can see Chinese that I suggest you can see my [blog](https://blog.csdn.net/lindexi_gd/article/details/52716655).

Comment: Sorry for my English.

Comment: It was no problem. Your explanation was easy to follow.